# Formula to reformat of names in excel where column A has Last, First, Middle but not always a middle

Tags: excel, format

I have a column of names (column A) formatted as "Last, First, Full Middle". 
 However, some of the names in column A do not have a middle name (i.e. only have "Last, First" or "Last, First, Middle initial").  I'm trying to come up with a formula (or multiple) that formats the names so that column B has "Last, First, Middle initial[period]" and column C has "Last, First Middle initial[period]"

E.g., if column A has: `Smith, John, David`
then I want column B to be: `Smith, John, D.`
and column C to be: `Smith, John D.`

I tried the following:
in column B:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",LEFT(A2,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","~",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))))+1)&".")
```

and in column c:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",SUBSTITUTE(B2,", "," ",LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""))))
```

Both formulas work EXCEPT if the name in column A doesn't have a middle name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in Column B:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","~",2))+1)&MID(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","~",2))+2,1)&".",A1)
```

and in Column C:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","~",2))-1)&" "&MID(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","~",2))+2,1)&".",A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!  The formula for column B works perfectly.  But it looks like the formula listed for column C is the same.  Is there a different version of the formula for column C?

Comment: @Joanna I copied the wrong formula for C.  See edit

Comment: @Joanna please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer

Comment: thanks again!  Just marked it complete (sorry, new to this site)!